# Problem with url with instance in react using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I use **react-router-dom** in my React project and everything was fine until I add one more **Route** like this:

```
<Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditPage}/>
```

then i change Url in browser to `http://localhost:8080/edit/123` then it's not render anything and in console it showed this warnings:

```
GEThttp://localhost:8080/edit/bundle.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 19ms]

The resource from “http://localhost:8080/edit/styles.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
123
The resource from “http://localhost:8080/edit/bundle.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
123
The resource from “http://localhost:8080/edit/scripts/bundle.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
123
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8080/edit/scripts/bundle.js”. 123:9:1
GEThttp://localhost:8080/edit/bundle.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3ms]

The resource from “http://localhost:8080/edit/bundle.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
123
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8080/edit/bundle.js”.
```

can anyone help please ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Added `<base href="/" />` to head tag of html file and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
http://localhost:8080/edit/bundle.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 19ms]
```

This seems to indicate you are using a `relative` path as the path of the bundle.js in your index.html.

You should use `absolute` path for bundle.js in your index.html

Something like this:

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

And not like this:

```
<script src="./bundle.js"></script>
```